# Как узнать список List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters? Который создается по-умолчанию?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

В моем приложении

```
@EnableWebMvc
```

Я могу сделать пустым метод

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    logger.fatal("configureMessageConverters start");
    logger.fatal(converters.toString());
    // MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    // converter.getObjectMapper().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
    // converter.getObjectMapper().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    // converters.add(converter);
    logger.fatal(converters.toString());
    logger.fatal("configureMessageConverters end");
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, в таком случае список конвертеров становится каким-то по-умолнчанию.

**Как мне получить этот список?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нам нужен `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`

Пробрасываем соответствующий бин в нужный нам пакет

```
@Autowired
WebMvcConfigurationSupport mvcConfigurationSupport;
```

И там где нам нужно получить список вызываем

```
mvcConfigurationSupport.getMessageConverters()
```

И получаем желаемый список.

Пример получения соответствующего списка в дебаггере на скрине ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Супер! Большое спасибо!